# Pandas Similar rows Search

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba, dataframe

How would I filter data on multiple criteria through the spreadsheet using python(pandas)?

I am trying to filter transactions with all **Curr1=USD**, where **Trade Time within 1 minute**, Have **the same Notional 1** and have **the Price** within .5% spread between transactions. Then the row with the furthest(highest) **Maturity** would be moved to a different Sheet in excel.

Example of the data:
[GoogleDrive Excel File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CUCdDsdFE48lEPhJxY6vqPJJxilR09ir/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101080637937411595323&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *Price within .5% spread between transactions*?

Comment: What should happen in case more than one row has the highest Maturity?

Comment: Let's say that: The difference between two prices cannot be larger than.5%
Only rows with the highest Maturity should be moved to a different sheet, while rows with lower maturity should be deleted from the current sheet.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you do not want to do this for a specific trade time / notional / price, but for each subset that meets these criteria?

Comment: @MichaelHodel, yes. The data is constantly changing (new rows add up). This file will split the data based on the Trade time within 1 minute and other criterias mentioned above, will shift data to Sheet1(lets call it)

BUT if the other transactions have the same Notional and Price and traded within 1 minute, then they should be moved to Sheet2.

I am not sure what is better to use here, VBA or Python considering sometime file has 40k+ cells and 12 columns.

Comment: I guess you want to group by instrument too (as otherwise price differences would not make much sense)? Thus, you expect something in the order of #minutes x #notionals x #instruments x #spread_segments many resulting groups over which you each individually want to take the argmax w.r.t maturity?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHodel Yes, is it even possible to do? If yes, by want package(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

path = 'Import.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'DifferentSheet'
currency = 'USD'
max_spread = 0.005

def filter_transactions(transactions, currency, max_spread):
    df = transactions.copy()
    df['Trade Time'] = df['Trade Time'].dt.round(freq='min')
    df = df[df['Curr 1'] == currency]
    instruments = set(df['Instrument'])
    cols = ['instrument', 'notional', 'minute', 'max_maturity', 'currency2', 'notional2']
    filtered_transactions = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    for instrument in instruments:
        df_instr = df[df['Instrument'] == instrument]
        for notional in set(df_instr['Notional 1']):
            df_notional = df_instr[df_instr['Notional 1'] == notional]
            minutes = pd.date_range(
                df_notional['Trade Time'].min(),
                df_notional['Trade Time'].max(),
                freq='min'
            )
            for minute in minutes:
                df_minute = df_notional[df_notional['Trade Time'] == minute]
                if df_minute.shape[0] > 0:
                    pricedeltas = df_minute['Price'][::-1].pct_change().fillna(0)[::-1]
                    deltacond = (pricedeltas.abs() <= max_spread)
                    max_maturity = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')
                    for cond, maturity, curr2, notional2 in zip(
                        deltacond, df_minute['Maturity'],
                        df_minute['Curr 2'], df_minute['Notional 2']
                    ):
                        if cond:
                            if maturity > max_maturity:
                                max_maturity = maturity
                        else:
                            obs = pd.DataFrame(
                                [[instrument, notional, minute, max_maturity, curr2, notional2]],
                                columns=cols
                            )
                            filtered_transactions = pd.concat([filtered_transactions, obs])
                            max_maturity = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')
    return filtered_transactions

def add_sheet(filtered_transactions, path, sheet_name):
    book = load_workbook(path)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    transactions_filtered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.save()

transactions = pd.read_excel(path)
transactions_filtered = filter_transactions(transactions, currency, max_spread)
add_sheet(transactions_filtered, path, sheet_name)
print(transactions_filtered)
```

prints

| index | instrument | notional | minute | max_maturity | currency2 | notional2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USD COP NDF | 17000000 | 2022-08-04 08:50:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | COP | 73380500000 |
| 1 | USD COP NDF | 4000000 | 2022-08-04 08:38:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | COP | 17304000000 |
| 2 | USD COP NDF | 1000000 | 2022-08-04 08:49:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | COP | 4326100000 |
| 3 | USD COP NDF | 10000000 | 2022-08-04 08:32:00 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | COP | 43260000000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This approach adds a new sheet to the existing Excel file with columns `['instrument', 'notional', 'minute', 'max_maturity', 'currency2', 'notional2']` that contains a row with the maximum observed maturity (and `'Currency 2'` as well as `'Notional 2'`) for each group of consecutive transactions with absolute prices differences less than 0.5% and identical `['instrument', 'notional' and 'minute']`, effectively filtering from `1113` down to just `112` rows.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! You are a lifesaver! 

One question: If I want to keep the Currency2 and The Notional2 In already filtered cells? How do I do that?

Comment: Sure, see edited answer